# openvpn issue avoid simultaneous access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn

How can i avoid openvpn users from using their keys simultaneously on two different computers.

For example :
I have got my openvpn keys . Now say i will install them on 10 computers and m able to connect all of them .

This is sort of security issue as well as i have very limited free IP addresses so i want vpn users  users their keys simultaneously.

Hope i sound alrite....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of OpenVPN is that you cannot use the same certificate simultaneously from multiple computers.  If you initiate a new connection with a certificate that's already in use, the existing connection will be dropped.

If you want to support simultaneous connections with the same certificate you need to enable the `duplicate-cn` option in your configuration.  From the man page:

```
   --duplicate-cn
          Allow multiple clients with the same common name to concurrently
          connect.  In the absence of this option, OpenVPN will disconnect
          a  client  instance  upon  connection of a new client having the
          same common name.
```

Comment: so that means at this stage --duplicate-cn is enabled ... if i disable it my problem will b solved. Is that right?

Comment: Did you solved?